# Using webkitdirectory to upload a directory, is it possible to filter out certain files prior to uploading?

Tags: javascript, webkit

I'm using [webkitdirectory](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement/webkitdirectory) to create an input that allows uploading an entire folder (rather than selecting individual files). I know it's non-standard and shouldn't be used in production.

I'm uploading a specific type of folder where there is one very large file that isn't needed, and many other small files. The upload takes a long time because there's a large file, but because coincidentally that's also the one file I don't actually need on the server side, I'm wondering if there's any way to filter it out prior to being uploaded?

Answer (score 2):

Should we assume that the large file has the same name pattern and/or content type as the files you want?  Otherwise it should be possible to exclude it from the selection by using the [`accept`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#attr-accept) attribute.

Otherwise I see 2 alternative approaches:

- Process the list of files on submit and construct a request containing only the ones you want to send, or
- Scan the `$(myInput).files` list in its `change` listener and copy everything you actually want to submit to another `<input name="filesField" type="file" multiple style="visibility: hidden">`

Comment: Using the `accept` attribute shouldn't make a difference because the user is not explicitly selecting files, but uploading an entire folder. I want to exclude certain files from within this folder. Your first approach looks promising if it can indeed work - how can I either slice the FileList of the original input or copy files from it to a different input? I'm not sure that's possibel

Comment: your answer has been auto-accepted, but I would really appreciate a followup that actually solves the problem, your suggestion is a good start but not an actual answer that can be implemented